# add a user to a list of users in manytomany field in django model when the object is created

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm very new to Django rest framework and am writing an API for an application in which you can manage a schedule for organizations. Users of this application can be registered as administrators to many organizations and organizations can have many admin users.

The trouble is that I want it so that when users create a new organization, they are added into a manytomany field upon saving the organization instance. I am having trouble getting the user who is making the request to be added

Here is my model:

```py
# models.py
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import (
    MinValueValidator,
    MaxValueValidator,
    EmailValidator,
    RegexValidator,
    URLValidator,
)


class OrgManager(models.Manager):

    def create(self, name, website, email, **kwargs):
        """Creates and saves a new org"""
        if not name:
            raise ValueError('Name was not provided for org')
        org = self.model(name=name, website=website, email=email, **kwargs)
        org.save(using=self._db)

        return org


class Org(TimeStampedModel):
    """A model for organizations"""
    # Required attributes
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=255,
                              validators=[URLValidator()],
                              unique=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255,
                             validators=[EmailValidator()],
                             unique=True)

    # Non-required attributes
    address_1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    address_2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True)
    zip_code = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True,
                                   validators=[MinValueValidator(10000),
                                   MaxValueValidator(99999)])
    phone = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True,
                             max_length=20, unique=True,                          
                             validators=[
                                 RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$')
                             ])

    objects = OrgManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

serializers.py

```py
# serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers

from org.models import Org
from user.serializers import UserSerializer


class OrgSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for the orgs object"""
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Org
        fields = (
            'name',  'address_1', 'address_2',
            'city',  'state',     'zip_code',
            'email', 'phone',     'website',
            'users',  'created',  'modified',
            'user'
        )
        read_only_fields = ('users', 'created', 'modified')
        extra_kwargs = {'user': {'write_only': True}}
```

views.py

```py
# views.py
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework import viewsets, mixins, generics

from org import serializers
from org.models import Org


class OrgsViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet,
                  mixins.ListModelMixin,
                  mixins.CreateModelMixin):
    """Manage orgs in the database"""
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Org.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.OrgSerializer
```

Now i haven't been able to figure out how to append to the user list upon object creation, and I'm not entirely sure that any of the documentation I've found explains how the request user can be added...

what's the best way to achieve this?

I'm not sure if I can use the `mixins.CreateModelMixin` appropriately. Is this possible?

I am using Django 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey you can add the login user in  list of instane

```
class OrgsViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet,
                  mixins.ListModelMixin,
                  mixins.CreateModelMixin):
    """Manage orgs in the database"""
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Org.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.OrgSerializer

   def perform_create(self, serializer):
       serializer.validated_data['users'] = [self.request.user]
       serializer.save()
```

Comment: ah I see how this works... So in theory you can add a decorator so that any perform_create function can inject into validated_data. something like ```@add_current_user```. Is this possible?

Comment: yaa you can write down your custom decorator

Comment: Ok, then assuming I have this set up, in order to limit results to only those associated with the current user, I assume this is in the get_queryset function?

Comment: such as ```def get_queryset(self): return self.queryset.filter(users__id=self.request.user.id)```